# the importlib.import_module has strange behavior in python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

The `importlib.import_module` with relative module name can fail sometime.

For example, I have a package structure like this:

```
├── test0
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test1.py
│   └── test2.py
├── test_impl.py
```

Test code like this:

```
import importlib
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
def test_imp_module(module_name, pkgname):
    try:
        _m = importlib.import_module(module_name, pkgname)
        print("import OK: module={}, pkg={}".format(module_name, pkgname))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

test_imp_module(".test1", "test0")
test_imp_module("test0.test1", "")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_imp_module(".test1", "test0")
    test_imp_module("test0.test1", "")
```

In Python3.5 it will fail the first test:

```
$ python3 test_impl.py 
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Parent module 'test0' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
import OK: module=test0.test1, pkg=
import OK: module=.test1, pkg=test0
import OK: module=test0.test1, pkg=
```

In python3.6 it works:

```
$ python3 test_impl.py 
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
import OK: module=.test1, pkg=test0
import OK: module=test0.test1, pkg=
import OK: module=.test1, pkg=test0
import OK: module=test0.test1, pkg=
```

Is this expected or a bug?
Update:
    Python2.7.12 has the same behavior as 3.6.

Comment: why 3.5 is expected? I thought the 1st and 3rd test should both fail or success. But 3.5 only success with 3rd one, which is very strange actually. If they both fail, then the relative module name never work, which is still unexpected.

Comment: Are you using [LazyLoader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.LazyLoader) at all?  Do `python3 -v test_impl.py |& grep LazyLoader`.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm not so sure, after seeing https://bugs.python.org/issue19963

Comment: @wim I think when <3.2, 1st and 3rd should always fail due to haven't load parent packages. But >3.4 they no longer require this thus should be always success. In either case the py3.5 behaved strangely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) say:

> `importlib.import_module(name, package=None)`
>
> ...
>
> *Changed in version 3.3:* Parent packages are automatically imported.

Therefore, the 3.6.4 behaviour is correct and the 3.5.2 behaviour is buggy.
You seem to be hitting [#30876](https://bugs.python.org/issue30876), and the issue says that was fixed in the version 5 micro i.e. v3.5.5.

<sub>Credit to *vaultah* in room 6 for [finding the ticket](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42082683#42082683).</sub>